# Include class file in controller in symfony2.0

Tags: symfony

I need to include a class file in the controller which is in the `web` directory.

Until now, I see the examples of the including file in namespaces under the `src` directory.

How do I include this class file?

Comment: This question is poorly worded and hard to understand. As well, please capitalize the first letter of each sentence, have a space after each `.`, and include what you tried, what worked, what didn't work.

Comment: I will edit your question so it is more grammatically correct and maybe it will become easier understood to others.

Comment: Do you even speak english?

Comment: Actually i want to include one php class file in to symfony controller file ..if its possible..?

Answer (score 0):

You should not put PHP classes under `web` directory. You can put such files under `vendor` or inside your bundle with namespaces. Then you can use the class. For example:

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use YourBundle\Lib\YourClass;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        $yourClass = new YourClass();
    }

    // ...
```